# How can I imitate that I am browsing from another country?

Tags: proxy, ip, vps, web

I would like to imitate that I'm browsing sites from another country, and as far as my knowledge goes, that can only be done with either VPS or Proxy servers. Note that I am looking for a solution that is **completely free.**

Again, as far as my knowledge goes:

You cannot get a VPS for free, unless you are okay with ads, slowness and other similar inconveniences, which I am not.

Proxy servers also cost money, unless they are slow and possibly offer other inconveniences, which I am, again, not okay with.

**So in short, is there any solution that wouldn't offer any inconvenience, is completely free and doesn't require me to have 2 PCs?**

P.S. I'm using both Windows and Linux, if that matters, mostly Windows though.

Comment: Intimate - to communicate delicately and indirectly - "Why hello mister server, I know you *think* I'm in the USA but please let me assure you I'm actually in merry old England drinking tea with the Queen and that's not the sound of my SUV crashing into my gun-mounted jetski, oh no..."

Comment: The question was also there to ask IF there are any implications for using such services, not only to get links to them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the IP's from the [proxy list](http://www.cool-proxy.net/proxies/http_proxy_list) . Add the Foxy proxy plugin in your firefox and switch to what ever ip you want.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the link part, unfortunately the question was closed off without the implication part getting answered. :/

Answer (score 1):

You mean you did a [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=free+web+proxy&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active) for "free web proxy" and didn't even find a link to [HMA](http://hidemyass.com) or any other likewise sites??